# Django Testing - check messages for a view that redirects

Tags: django, redirect, testing, message, django-context

I have been writing tests for one of my django applications and have been looking to get around this problem for quite some time now. I have a view that sends messages using `django.contrib.messages` for different cases. The view looks something like the following.

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import redirect

import custom_messages

def some_view(request):
    """ This is a sample view for testing purposes.
    """

    some_condition = models.SomeModel.objects.get_or_none(
        condition=some_condition)
    if some_condition:
        messages.success(request, custom_message.SUCCESS)
    else:
        messages.error(request, custom_message.ERROR)
    redirect(some_other_view)
```

Now, while testing this view `client.get`'s response does not contain the `context` dictionary that contains the `messages` as this view uses a redirect. For views that render templates we can get access to the messages list using `messages = response.context.get('messages')`. How can we get access `messages` for a view that redirects?

Comment: Not sure if this will fit your need but you can pass get variables to identify what has happened: `redirect(reverse(some_other_view) + '?user_added=true')`

Comment: I am actually already testing the condition being used in the view in my test. Here I am talking about explicitly testing the message that was sent.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use the `follow=True` option in the [`client.get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.get) call, and the client will follow the redirect. You can then test that the message is in the context of the view you redirected to.

```
def test_some_view(self):
    # use follow=True to follow redirect
    response = self.client.get('/some-url/', follow=True)

    # don't really need to check status code because assertRedirects will check it
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertRedirects(response, '/some-other-url/')

    # get message from context and check that expected text is there
    message = list(response.context.get('messages'))[0]
    self.assertEqual(message.tags, "success")
    self.assertTrue("success text" in message.message)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Though, using `follow=True` changes the expected redirect code from `302` to `200` as it follows the redirected view.

Comment: Yes, following the redirect means that the response has status code 200. There is an [`assertRedirects`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/overview/#django.test.TestCase.assertRedirects) method that you can use to test the redirect.

Comment: yup, that's what i am using now :)

Comment: This also works for `client.post()` to add `follow=True`

Comment: You can't access elements in messages directly with messages[0], you have to convert it to a list or tuple – list(messages)

Comment: @bbrik the answer has now been updated, sorry I didn't see your comment sooner.

Answer (score 8):

You can use get_messages() with response.wsgi_request like this (tested in Django 1.10):

```
from django.contrib.messages import get_messages  
...
def test_view(self):
    response = self.client.get('/some-url/') # you don't need follow=True
    self.assertRedirects(response, '/some-other-url/')
    # each element is an instance of  django.contrib.messages.storage.base.Message
    all_messages = [msg for msg in get_messages(response.wsgi_request)]

    # here's how you test the first message
    self.assertEqual(all_messages[0].tags, "success")
    self.assertEqual(all_messages[0].message, "you have done well")
```

Comment: This worked for me, whereas the Alasdair's method didn't show any messages. I'm on Django 1.11.

Answer (score 1):

If your views are redirecting and you use `follow=true` in your request to the test client the above doesn't work.  I ended up writing a helper function to get the first (and in my case, only) message sent with the response.

```
@classmethod
def getmessage(cls, response):
    """Helper method to return message from response """
    for c in response.context:
        message = [m for m in c.get('messages')][0]
        if message:
            return message
```

You include this within your test class and use it like this:

```
message = self.getmessage(response)
```

Where `response` is what you get back from a `get` or `post` to a `Client`.

This is a little fragile but hopefully it saves someone else some time.

Comment: You don't need that list comprehension, just use list(messages) or tuple(messages).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when using a 3rd party app.

If you want to get the messages from a view that returns an HttpResponseRedict (from which you can't access the context) from within another view, you can use [`get_messages(request)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#django.contrib.messages.get_messages)

```
from django.contrib.messages import get_messages  

storage = get_messages(request)  
for message in storage:  
    do_something_with_the_message(message)
```

This clears the message storage though, so if you want to access the messages from a template later on, add:

```
storage.used = False
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative method mocking messages (doesn't need to follow redirect):

```
from mock import ANY, patch
from django.contrib import messages

@patch('myapp.views.messages.add_message')
def test_some_view(self, mock_add_message):
    r = self.client.get('/some-url/')
    mock_add_message.assert_called_once_with(ANY, messages.ERROR, 'Expected message.')  # or assert_called_with, assert_has_calls...
```