# How can I unit test django messages... with a HTTPResponseRedirect?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-messages

[Just like this question... but harder.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897609/how-can-i-unit-test-django-messages)

I have a view that redirects a user, and uses the [Django messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/messages/) to send them to the right page, and adds a message with code like that below:

```
def new_comment(request,pid):
    post = get_object_or_404(DiscussionPost,pk=pid)
    if post.closed:
        messages.error(request, _('This post is closed. Your comment was not added.'))
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("discussionsPost",args=[post.pk]))
```

Now this works well for a user, but when testing the messages aren't available.

In the unit test I do:

```
    response = self.client.post(reverse('aristotle:discussionsPostNewComment',args=[p1.id]),
        {'body':"Post is closed, so I can NOT comment."}
    )
    #the below assertion passes
    self.assertRedirects(response,reverse('aristotle:discussionsPost',args=[p1.id]))

    print response
    print response.context['messages']
```

And the first print gives:

```
Vary: Accept-Language, Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: http://testserver/discussions/post/1
Content-Language: en
```

With the second failing with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/aristotle_mdr/tests/main/test_discussions.py", line 393, in test_post_to_closed_discussion
    print response.context['messages']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Plus there its not possible to use [`messages.get_messages`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/messages/#django.contrib.messages.get_messages) as there is no request item that can be used.

**Since, there is no context dictionary in `HTTPResponseRedirect`, how can I check whether the message was sent properly?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Testing - check messages for a view that redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143149/django-testing-check-messages-for-a-view-that-redirects)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to test the response *after* the redirect, then you need to tell the Django test client to "follow" the redirect chain, via the `follow` argument. As stated in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.post):

> If you set follow to True the client will follow any redirects and a redirect_chain attribute will be set in the response object containing tuples of the intermediate urls and status codes.

So your test post would need to look something like:

```
    response = self.client.post(
        reverse('aristotle:discussionsPostNewComment', args=[p1.id]),
        {'body':"Post is closed, so I can NOT comment."},
        follow=True
    )
```

Comment: Yup. This is exactly it. Thanks!